# openVPN - Split-tunneling DNS priority

Tags: openvpn

I have commented out the (push "redirect-gateway def1") to turn our openVPN appliance into a split-tunneling mode.

```
#push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "route 172.21.1.0 255.255.248.0"
push "route 10.61.255.0 255.255.240.0"
```

However, seems I'm not able to control which DNS resolution goes to which.
(as in whether servers sent inquiries to 8.8.8.8 vs internal dns 10.2.1.1 in our case)

I know in Windows, users can set DNS preference.

Is there some universal option across Mac/Win/Linux?

Thanks.

[Update: looking at comments, this seems not possible. Then shall I set internal 1st and public 2nd? What's the best practice within split-tunnel? In terms of DNS resolution in simplest way possible]

Comment: `some universal option`.  Nope.  Name resolution usually happens before a routing decision happens, so how would something know which interface it is going out?

Comment: So I guess set internal DNS as default so that any internal stuff doesn't get left out then use public DNS?

Comment: When you configure multiple DNS servers on a client, it may use any of them at any time.  Some clients cycle through.  In any case, it doesn't try one, then use another, unless there was a server failure.  A NXDOMAIN, or getting a valid record that doesn't route anywhere, will not result in the client trying another DNS server.

Comment: Please see update

Answer (score 1):

workaround on "`abc.ovpn`" file on client side and NOT on server side fixed the problem.

Add "`--block-outside-dns`" and your internal DNS will be overruled by the one given by OpenVPN's TAP adapter.